# Performing exact tests for small samples

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, exact-test

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a finite set (it has, let's say, ten elements), and $p$ a probability on $\mathcal{X}$. Let $n$ be an integer, that we assume to be small (let's say, $n=10$).
Given an $n$-tuple $\mathbf{x} := (x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ of elements of $X$, let us denote, for all $x$, $o_x(\mathbf{x})$ the cardinal of the set of $j$’s such that $x_j(x)=x$. Consider the $T$-statistics: $T(\mathbf{x}) := n\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}o_x(\mathbf{x}) - p_x\right)^2}{p_x}$.

The sample size, $n$, is too small (is it really? I don't know how to tell) to assume that if $\mathbf{X} := (X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is a random $n$-tuple of independent variables of law $p$, then the law of $T(\mathbf{X})$ is sufficiently close to the $\chi^2(\vert \mathcal{X} \vert -1)$ law.

However, $n$ looks too large to perform an exact test in the naive way! Indeed, the law of $T(\mathbf{X})$ has maybe $10^{10}$ atoms, so it is probably pointless to try to compute it. I could also simulate a large number of realizations of $\mathbf{X}$ and compute the quantiles, I don't know how to estimate how many simulations I need to run in order to obtain a simulated quantile that is close to the real one, but I expect the number of required simulations to be quite high.

EDIT: I guess I forgot to write the precise question...
How does one perform exact tests, in practice? In particular, how does one compute the quantiles of the distribution of the statistic, assuming the data follows a known law?

EDIT2: I don't have any real application in mind. It is just that I want to test the assertion saying that "one should not use the $\chi^2$-test for small samples" by comparing with the exact test.

Comment: What's your question?  Please note there must be some typographical errors in your formula for $T,$ which makes the entire post incomprehensible, because we can't be sure what you're writing about.  It would be better to describe your application rather than trying to frame it so abstractly, because then your description would survive minor errors, but an abstract mathematical question has to be absolutely perfect.

Comment: Maybe the number I wanted to wrote is called differently. I see no typographical error. Can you spot a difference between what I wrote and the formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic ?

Comment: Sorry, I found a typographical error, and corrected it!

Comment: I don't understand your statistic; you appear to be taking the absolute value of the index $j$ - which, being an index, is an integer and positive anyway - for those indices where $x_j = x$, then subtracting $p_x$ from this integer value, dividing by $n$ and squaring the result for the numerator.

Comment: Well, there should be {,} signs around this part of the expression. They didn’t appear at start, but now they do for me. It should read « the number of $j$´s such that $x_j=x$ ».